# Checking incoming message in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am implementing a duplex WCF service with client and server. I have control over both client and server applications. I have setup service host and when I open the host as `host.Open();` I have to check when a message has arrived so I can perform certain task. Question is how do I listen to the incoming messages so when a new message comes in, I can perform certain task.
I believe it will use `OperationContext.Current` but not sure which command to use.

Comment: Isn't this of help: [Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)?

Comment: On the server side, the implementation of the ServiceContract (one of the OperationContract method) would be called. On the client side, the implementation of your interface defined as CallbackContract will be called.